# Git always not committing modified file

Tags: git

```
git status
```

returns the following:

> modified: myApp/src/main/java/com/myPackage/MyClass.java

No matter what I do, git add, git commit, etc.. does not actually commit the file.

So, I add a new branch and try to commit there.

But when I use IntelliJ to commit, it still says

> "0 files committed, 1 file failed to commit: Commit On branch myNewBranch Changes not staged for commit: modified: myApp/src/main/java/com/myPackage/MyClass.java"

How to fix it? Why is the modified file not committing? I am the only one working on this.

Comment: You need to stage the changes, `git add .` is usually the trick but please read about how git manages commits first.

Comment: As mentioned above `git add .`  or  `git add -A` will add all uncommitted files and modification.

Comment: What happens when you try to add? What does `git diff` show? Does `git stash` work properly on this modified file?

Comment: Try `git ls-files | grep -i myApp/src/main/java/com/myPackage/MyClass.java`. If it prints more than one file, you have some files with the same path except letter case, which causes the problem on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Lasse already, you have to stage the changes. Within IntelliJ you can do so by pressing `Ctrl+K` or navigating to `VCS > Commit...`. The next window allows you to select whole files or only parts to add. After choosing the parts that should be included in your commit/patch you have to fill in the `Commit Message` field and either press `Commit` or `Ctrl+Enter`.

Comment: Not true, already did it multiple times. with Intellij and with cmd.

Comment: Sorry if this was not helpful. It is hard to help further with the information you provided.